# Proving a sequence to be divergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, radicals

I'm trying to prove this sequence: $a_n = \sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n^2-1}$ to be divergent. How would I do this? I'm thinking of proving that it's not bounded below, but I'm not sure how to do that with induction, as I've only done that to prove it's bounded.

Comment: How is it convergent?

Comment: It is not convergent. It diverges to -$\infty$

Comment: @David, that's what I'm thinking.

Comment: Recheck the equation Andre this is not convergent.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I read it as $n-\sqrt{n^2-1}$.

Comment: @ElectronicGeek First can you show that $a_n > a_{n+1}$. For all $n$?

Comment: That's where I'm stuck at. I know how to do that for recursive integrals, but I don't know how to do that with all the radicals in the equation. Could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
a_n = \sqrt{n} - \sqrt{n^2-1} = \sqrt{n} - n\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n^2}} = \sqrt{n}\underbrace{\left( 1-\sqrt{n}\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n^2}}\right)}_{b_n}
$$
Now, $\sqrt{n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty$; and $\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n^2}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1$, so $\sqrt{n}\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n^2}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}+\infty$ and thus $b_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}-\infty$.

Finally, this implies that $a_n=\sqrt{n}b_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}-\infty$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: compare the sequence $a_n=\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n^2-1}$ to the sequence $b_n=-\sqrt{n}$, which clearly diverges to $-\infty$.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, but how would I show that $b_n \geq a_n$?

Comment: @ElectronicGeek I was going to say algebraically, but I tried for myself and it is admittedly rather difficult. I edited my answer to offer a more suitable comparison series that should be easier to verify.